# iOS 8: being notified of CKRecord changes via subscriptions

Tags: swift, ios8, cloudkit

I'm running a `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation` to pull down all update notifications that were supposedly sent since the last time my app ran.

I'm getting a bunch of `CKNotification` objects, as I'd expect but the `recordFields` object of every one of these CKNotification is nil. I expected it to be populated with all the changed attributes of my object. 
But maybe that's not the case.

I'm not specifying the `desiredKeys` attribute of the `CKSubscription` object, which apparently would force the `CKNotification` `recordFields` to hold that data. But the docs say `desiredKeys` can only have 3 values and my objects have a lot more than 3 values that could be updated.

So now I'm thinking, I just need to take the `CKNotification` object, see if it's an update, then re-fetch the object it's pointing to to retrieve its data. Then I can do a diff on the new `CKRecord` vs. the old to see what's changed.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: "But the docs say desiredKeys can only have 3 values and my objects have a lot more than 3 values that could be updated" ... where does it say that? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to store `CKServerChangeToken` provided by `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation`

```
var notificationChangesOperation = CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: previousChangeToken)

var fetchedRecordIDs:[CKRecordID]()

//we just care about inserts, we don't care about of changes of records existing in database, that's why it's enough just to save recordIDs
notificationChangesOperation.notificationChangedBlock = {notification in

    let queryNotif = notification as CKQueryNotification
    //            println("fetched  CKQueryNotification \(queryNotif)")

    if (!contains(fetchedRecordIDs, queryNotif.recordID)) {
        fetchedRecordIDs.append(queryNotif.recordID)
    }
}

notificationChangesOperation.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = {serverChangeToken, error in
    if (error) {
        println("failed to fetch notification \(error)")
    }

    self.previousChangeToken = serverChangeToken

    completionHandler(recordIDs: fetchedRecordIDs, error: error)
}

container.addOperation(notificationChangesOperation)

var previousChangeToken:CKServerChangeToken? {
    get {
        let encodedObjectData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(SubscriptionKeys.PreviousChangeToken) as? NSData

        if (encodedObjectData) {
            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(encodedObjectData) as? CKServerChangeToken
        }

        return nil
    }
    set(newToken) {
        if (newToken) {
            println("new token \(newToken)")

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(newToken), forKey:SubscriptionKeys.PreviousChangeToken)
        }
    }
}
```

and then pass it in next calls of `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation`. Then this operation will provide you with updates since your last request. `CKNotification` (`CKQueryNotification`) provides you with `CKRecordID` objects, not `CKRecord`.

So you need to refetch all `CKRecord`s for these IDs using `CKFetchRecordsOperation` and update you model objects accordingly.

```
func queryMessagesWithIDs(IDs:[CKRecordID], completionHandler: ([CKRecord]!, NSError!) -> Void) {
    var fetchRecordsOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: IDs)

    var messages:[CKRecord]()

    fetchRecordsOperation.perRecordCompletionBlock = {record, recordID, error in
        if (!error) {
            messages.append(record)
        } else {
            println("failed to get message with ID \(recordID.recordName)")
        }
    }

    fetchRecordsOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = {_, error in
        if (error) {
            println(error)
        } else {
            messages.sort{$0.creationDate.compare($1.creationDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending}
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {completionHandler(messages, error)})
    }

    publicDatabase.addOperation(fetchRecordsOperation)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation is deprecated in iOS 11, in the header Apple suggest:

*"Instead of iterating notifications to enumerate changed record zones, use CKDatabaseSubscription, CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation, and CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation"*

Comment: How is this better than using CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation? And don't I still have to do a CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation anyway?

Comment: CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation has been deprecated in favor of CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation  and CKFetchRecordChangesOperation